# In OOP what are the different meanings of interface in the different contexts they apply to

Tags: oop, user-interface, interface

I'm a bit new to object oriented programming. On my journey I have come across something that has had me confused for a few days now. It is the term "interface" and how it has **different meanings in different contexts and even different programming languages**. I want to understand "interface" but when I do my research I seem to get different definitions as if it has multiple meanings.

Would someone kindly give me a concise definition of interface in each context (just the main ones)?

I purchased a book called **the object oriented thought process** by Matt Weisfeld where **some** of them have been identified which are below:

1. Graphical user interface
2. The interface to a class is basically the signatures of its methods
3. Objective-C code can be broken up into physically separate modules called interface and impelentation
4. A Java-style interface and an Objective-C protocol are basically the contract between a parent class and a child class

(Are there any more uses/definitions of the term interface in OOP than those identified above?)

If someone would kindly explain the different contexts of the term interface in OOP it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Think of an interface as where two or more things can meet and interact

Comment: Sidenote: A graphical user interface (GUI) is not necessarily related to OOP.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a discussion question about terminology, not a specific programming question. It is more appropriate for [programmers.se].

Comment: Interface is just a contract between two parties so that they know how to handshake . Say if person A wants to communicate to person B , A should know what language does B speaks/understands ,similarly in software you are defining that this is the contract of my class and you can use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer:

Your 4th bullet point probably comes closest to the generally accepted notion of what OOP interfaces are: *contracts* between parties that need to interact with one another. Such contracts define the means (a) provided by one party, and (b) required by the other, in order to do so.

### Long answer:

Very generally speaking, an interface is a thing that allows two (possibly very different) entities to interact with each other; it enables them to work together while at the same time allowing them to stay apart. The interface is the "common ground" that both parties agree on.

(Can be as simple as a door lock: Both the lock and any key able to work it must "fit together" in one place; you could call that place the interface.)

**How does this general definition apply to your list?**

> *Graphical user interface*

A GUI allows humans and computer programs to interact. It does not require the computer to become fully human (and listen with ears, talk with the mouth, smile, etc.), neither does it require of the human to become a computer program itself. (UIs from past decades excluded. :)

> *"The interface to a class is basically the signatures of its methods"*

The (publicly visible) methods and their exact signatures are the only means by which other types are going to be able to interact with that class, so in that sense, they together form that class' interface.

Also, a general description of each constructor and method is typically a part of the interface as well as a short general description of the purpose of the class and each of its methods. And of course, the name of the class itself -- pretty important.

> *"Objective-C code can be broken up into physically separate modules called interface and [implementation]"*

I don't know Objective-C well enough to comment on that, but many languages have a module system that allows you to partition your codebase into separate, functionally independent modules. These usually don't have to expose all their types and functions to outsiders; each module may carefully declare what can be seen by other modules. As above, all that is chosen to be exposed is the "interface", because it will be the only way to interact with whatever is in the module. That "whatever is in the module" stays hidden; it's called the "implementation", and outsiders should not have to know about it.

> *"A Java-style interface and an Objective-C protocol are basically the contract between a parent class and a child class"*

This is perhaps what comes closest to the generally accepted notion of interfaces in OOP: That they are **contracts between** parties that want to interact. See short answer at the beginning of this question.

Basically, a Java `interface` allows us to describe a group of methods and their exact signatures, but it won't allow us to provide the implementation. Therefore it's a pure interface; it cannot be called directly. It only describes *how one could interact with* a class that actually implemented it. (The two parties do not necessarily have to be "parent" and "child".)

Ideally, an interface should not just state what one class has to offer; it should also describe what a typical consumer will need, thereby keeping the interface focused in a well-encapsulated system. (I am referring to the [Single-Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) here.)

Comment: Great that was clear and concise. I just have 2 issues regarding all this then. In regard to the java interface, what does it achieve? what is its purpose and the benefits/power it provides? Also are there any other uses for the term interface in OOP other than the ones we have discussed?

Comment: @MohsinG: Regarding your last question, what I'm trying to show in my answer is that "interface" is a word like any other and OOP does not reinvent its fundamental meaning. While there *is* a widespread understanding of OOP "interfaces" as Java-like `interface`s, this does not mean that the word cannot be used to describe other things that exhibit to the same basic characteristics.

Comment: @MohsinG: Concerning your first few follow-up questions, these are really different questions. I have only little space to answer them here, so suffice it to say that `interface`s force you to take a step back and think what your system is really trying to achieve, and how its single parts will work together. Because you cannot provide concrete implementations, these (a) won't distract you during this important design step, and (b) will become replaceable/exchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Interface is a concept of abstraction and encapsulation. It is basically a contract you should comply to or given to ie, Interface is just a contract between two parties so that they know how they will interact with each other. An interface generally defines how you can interact with a class, the methods that it supports.

An interface contains only the signatures of the methods. The methods dont have anything neither interface can do anything. It is just a pattern.

[image]

Now in this anAbstarctMethod() is the Interface which is defined and it only has signatures but it doesnot have the implementation. Now when the class ASubClass implements the ineterface then the actual implementation is provided to the interface.

As far as Graphical user Interface is concerned I dont think that may necessarily be Object Oriented Programming. The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) says that a graphical user interface is just a user interface through which you can interact with the electronic devices through icons and other indicators.

[image]

The [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) has given a good example for this:-

> Methods form the object's interface with the outside world; the
>   buttons on the front of your television set, for example, are the
>   interface between you and the electrical wiring on the other side of
>   its plastic casing. You press the "power" button to turn the
>   television on and off.

A good example from [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/interfaces.html):-

> An interface is a description of the actions that an object can do...
>   for example when you flip a light switch, the light goes on, you don't
>   care how, just that it does. **In Object Oriented Programming, an
>   Interface is a description of all functions that an object must have
>   in order to be an "X"**. Again, as an example, anything that "ACTS LIKE"
>   a light, should have a turn_on() method and a turn_off() method. The
>   purpose of interfaces is to allow the computer to enforce these
>   properties and to know that an object of TYPE T (whatever the
>   interface is ) must have functions called X,Y,Z, etc.

You may also check **[Why Use Interfaces?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260635%28v=vs.60%29.aspx#ifacebased_whyuse)**

> Another powerful design technique is to have a single class implement
>   multiple interfaces. If you do this, you will have objects that
>   support multiple interfaces and, therefore, multiple behaviors. When
>   used together with run-time type inspection, this becomes very
>   powerful.

Answer (score 0):

In OOP, the term "interface" means basically all the method signatures for all the messages that can be sent to objects of a class. So in Objective-C, it would be all the method declarations in the header file.

The term "Graphical User Interface" is not using the word "interface" in an OO context.
Item #2 on your list is an OO interface.
Item #3 is referring to the .h and .m files.
Item #4 refers to the keyword 'interface' in the Java language and equating it to the keyword 'protocol' in the objective-C language.

Answer (score -1):

General meaning:

An Interface is essentially something that interacts with something else

For example: An interface can be with a python application and the Skype-API (thought off the top of my head xD)

Comment: No, an interface does not interact *itself*. It is only the thing that *makes it possible for two other things to* interact with each other.

Answer (score -1):

An interface is a form of multiple inheritance (without the 'alleged' complications that brings) (it's a controversial subject)

OO is founded on the "is a" relationship, MI (multiple inheritance) allows an object to be several things. Interfaces define a way for them to be these things, without an implementation.

They are "what you must to _*to be a _* whatever".

Comment: Both of "An interface is a form of multiple inheritance" and "OO is founded on the "is a" relationship" are patently false. An interface is not a form of multiple inheritance (you can use them in multiple inheritance scenarios but it is far from the main point of interfaces) nor is OO founded on the is-a relationship (OO is many things, but this one you cite is news to me as being a core part of it)